# Try and catch arguments

Tags: c#, arguments, try-catch

I am relatively new to c# and the idea of using try{} cathch{}. In my code below I want the `try` to execute as long as there is a valid integer in the text box. I already have the text box set up so no non integer char can be enter, and the integer cannot be too high, so that is not a problem. If that text box is left blank the code should jump to catch, which it does. However, I am wondering what argument I should use for this catch, and also if I could move my `if(samplingRate == 0)` to a catch somehow.

```
try
{
    int samplingRate = int.Parse(tbSamplingRate.Text); // sampling rate bytes
    if(samplingRate == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sampling Rate Cannot Equal Zero");
        improperDataEntry = 1;
    }

    int sr1 = samplingRate / (16 * 16 * 16);
    samplingRate = samplingRate - sr1 * (16 * 16 * 16);
    int sr2 = samplingRate / (16 * 16);
    samplingRate = samplingRate - (sr2 * 16 * 16);
    int sr3 = samplingRate / 16;
    samplingRate = samplingRate - sr3 * 16;
    int sr4 = samplingRate;
    int srByte1 = sr1 * 16 + sr2;
    int srByte2 = sr3 * 16 + sr4;

    if (Convert.ToByte(srByte1) == 0xC0) // this handles if a C0 or a DB is encountered
    {
        sendPackage.Add(0xDB);
        sendPackage.Add(0xDC);
    }
    else if (Convert.ToByte(srByte1) == 0xDB)
    {
        sendPackage.Add(0xDB);
        sendPackage.Add(0xDD);
    }
    else
        sendPackage.Add(Convert.ToByte(srByte1));

    if (Convert.ToByte(srByte2) == 0xC0) // this handles if a C0 or a DB is encountered
    {
        sendPackage.Add(0xDB);
        sendPackage.Add(0xDC);
    }
    else if (Convert.ToByte(srByte2) == 0xDB)
    {
        sendPackage.Add(0xDB);
        sendPackage.Add(0xDD);
    }
    else
        sendPackage.Add(Convert.ToByte(srByte2));
}
catch
{
    improperDataEntry = 1;
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a sampling rate.");
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use try/catch for this at all - I'd use `int.TryParse`, so you can detect invalid input without using exceptions at all.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton, does that just return a bool? If so I am guessing you think it would be best to just handle this with some if, else statements?

Comment: It returns a `bool`, but stores the parsed value in an `out` parameter. So yes, you'd use an `if` statement to try to parse the value, report an error and return early if necessary - then keep going otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should avoid using try/catch for flow of control. It should be used only for exceptional or unexpected circumstances. Instead, use TryParse to determine if the number can be parsed. Also, don't be afraid to `return` early if validation does not pass.

```
int samplingRate;
bool ok = int.TryParse(tblSamplingRate.Text, out samplingRate);
if (!ok)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.");
    improperDataEntry = 1;
    return;
}
if(samplingRate == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sampling Rate Cannot Equal Zero");
    improperDataEntry = 1;
    return;
}
```

If you insist on using the `try` block, you will want to catch [FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx). You can see what exceptions Parse can throw by checking the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I will do this but change the second if to an else if,  and then add an else at the end that will execute if everything is valid

Comment: You shouldn't need an else if you are calling `return` when validation fails. See [this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) for information on why this is significant.

Comment: This code is inside of a method that returns a byte array. So I don't think I can just return.

Comment: nevermind, I just return the byte array early. It works like I want it to still